# Etymology for "cacamayme"

Tags: etymology, orthography

I love using "cacamayme" in conversations when I really want to emphasize the "crazy" I am talking about.

I also love the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cacamayme)'s slang definition:

> 100% grade A Bologna.

Does anyone know where this word comes from, or how many different ways it can be spelled?

Edit - It looks as though the spelling I am using is Yiddish — [here is a link](http://bageldrive.com/?page_id=3).

Comment: I actually just found the etymology myself @FumbleFingers - it is Yiddish and it has an alternative spelling of Kokamayme.  If someone wants to close because I just found my own answer though that is okay with me.

Comment: @FumblFingers Try the more common spelling, *cockamamie* -- 427,000 hits.

Comment: @Rachel Multiple sources I found say that the Yiddish connection isn't correct, though it's a common misconception.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick my bubbe would be ashamed. What about the link I added to my question?  I do realize it isn't the most educational of choices to cite, let me work a bit harder to find another.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick: Ooops! Well, I can't rescind my vote to close, but no matter. It doesn't look likely it's Yiddish though - it was apparently 'wildly popular' in the 186os, and is thought to be of [French origin](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-coc1.htm)

Comment: @Rachel Just so you know, it is ok to answer your own question when you find a possible answer. You can always wait a little bit to see if someone else is able to provide an answer you would rather accept.

Comment: @Rachel: Sorry about my unseemly haste to close. Even if you're happy you've found your own answer there's no reason your question can't sit here in perpetuity for others who wonder the same thing. But they've been wondering for 150 years now, and still there's no certainty as to the origin. So I doubt ELU is going to finally crack this one!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is quite alright, apology accepted.  I can now see why one would want to move towards the action of closure...although I was definitely not looking to stump my unknown peers with a question that really had no possible answer.  I honestly had no idea this word was so shrouded in mystery so to speak.  I agree wholeheartedly though, I was just hoping someone had more knowledge than I did. :)

Comment: broken link to bageldrive.com

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The more common spelling is **Cockamamie**, which provides some likely suspects. [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cockamamie) and [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/weirdwords/ww-coc1.htm) suggest that it's a jumbled and easier-to-pronounce version of the French *décalcomanie*, also source of the English *decal*.

Apparently decals were popular with children in New York City in the 1920s or '30s, where they came with candy and gum. How exactly cockamamie got its current meaning isn't entirely clear, though it likely relates to the frivolousness of these decals.

Comment: +1 - this is definitely a wonderful definition.  I think it will garner the answer vote.

Comment: Looks like this is absolutely right. From Henry Roth's 1934 novel *Call It Sleep:* "I cud buy fuh two cends cockamamies an' pud em on mine hull arm" (New York Jewish immigrant child speaking), although the singular is spelled *cockamamy* in this book.

Comment: The OED's first citation for the decal sense is from 1931 and they have *children's slang* for the origin. It was still in use in NYC in the '50s. I heard it used (for *ridiculous*) the other night on a news show.

Answer (score 1):

The actual word is cockamamie, and according to [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/cockamamie) it is:

> Probably alteration of decalcomania.