# Where did the word "cocamame" come from?

Tags: word-choice, etymology

Where did the word "cocamame" come from, and how did it get its connotation of meaning "idiotic"?

Is "cocamame" considered to be more or less severe than "idiotic" on the scale of idiocy?

Are there any words that would be even more idiotic than cocamame?

Comment: That's a misspelling of [cockamamie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=cockamamie&searchmode=none)

Comment: @MattЭллен - Thanks for pointing out the correct spelling. Looking for that spelling, I also find "cacamayme" given as yet another spelling in the question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35412/etymology-for-cacamayme

Answer (score 4):

**Cockamamie** comes from [the French word](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cockamamie) décalcomanie, a word used to describe the popular use of children's rub-on tattoos. It is another one of many words meaning *foolish*. The extent of foolishness described by the word is subjective.

Comment: It is used in Charmed 4x02 "Charmed Again", t=22:43